# Bootstrap 4 match grid columns size in different blocks

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

This is the layout I need to achieve:

[image: layout]

Columns to match size are marked with green. I can't fix columns size, they have to stay responsive.
I have tried to create nested row in block 2, but cannot match the size since col-2 in nested row is different from col-2 in parent row...

Attempt code:

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      col-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w-100">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          col-10
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
          col-10
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          col-2 ???
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your attempt as well? We will be of better help with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: which version?..

Comment: Version is Bootstrap 4

Comment: Have added code attempt

Comment: you need to reset a min-width to that col so it adjust . the col-8 can be turned into col to avoid messing it up.  col-2 inside a row of ten instead 12 becomes a 20% element . you can try this : https://jsfiddle.net/x0q8p5co/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```css
[class^="col"] {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: #afd095;
}
.w-20{min-width:20%}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>Block 1</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      col-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 bg-green ">
      col-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Block 2</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          col-10
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          col-8
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 bg-green w-20">
          col-2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```